# Hide not working using jquery

Tags: jquery, list, hide

I am trying to do some thing like this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var userType = '<%=Session["UserType"]%>';
            if (userType != "Admin") {
                alert("Inside If Block");
                $("#bodycontent").addClass("hide");
            }
            else {
            }
        });
    </script>
```

But, the body content is not hiding. I was getting the page as it is..

Please help..

I am trying to hide the page content if condditon is satisfied

Comment: does the alert execute ?

Comment: You are adding a class not actually hiding anything, is it defined in your css ? You can just use `$("#bodycontent").hide()`

Comment: should be `$("#bodycontent").hide()` but you should post some html too

Answer (score 1):

You need to define you class hide on css like:

```
.hide { display: none; }
```

Or simply do this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var userType = '<%=Session["UserType"]%>';
            if (userType != "Admin") {
                alert("Inside If Block");
                $("#bodycontent").hide();
            }
            else {
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: OP might be from `.net` or `java`.

Comment: Looks like classic ASP.

Comment: U duh, sure. I'm used to PHP tags and forget it isn't.

Comment: @All..Its MVC not classic ASP

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
  $("#bodycontent").addClass("hide");
```

with

```
  ("#bodycontent").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this .....
Replace

```
        $("#bodycontent").addClass("hide");
```

with

```
        $("#bodycontent").attr("style","display:none");
```

...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var userType = '<%=Session["UserType"]%>';
            if (userType != "Admin") {
                alert("Inside If Block");
                $("#bodycontent").attr("style","display:none");
            }
            else {
            }
        });
    </script>
```